# How to left join when only matched one record from right table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know How to left join when only matched one record from right table.
For example,

tableA

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 |
| 2 | 42 |
| 3 | 60 |

tableB

| id | value | tableA_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 2 | 31 | 1 |
| 3 | 50 | 2 |

I want to get result like below using `left outer join`.

| tableA_id | tableA_value | tableB_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | null |
| 2 | 42 | 50 |
| 3 | 60 | null |

tableB_value of first row is null, because `tableA.id = tableB.tableA_id` matches multiple records.

how to solve it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `COUNT()` as an analytic function to keep track of how many times a `tableA_id` occurs in the A table:

```sql
SELECT a.id AS tableA_id, a.value AS tableA_value, b.value AS tableB_value
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tableA_id) cnt
    FROM tableB
) b
    ON a.id = b.tableA_id AND b.cnt = 1
ORDER BY a.id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using aggregation on the `b` table as well:

```
SELECT a.id AS tableA_id, a.value AS tableA_value, b.value AS tableB_value
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT tableA_id, MAX(value) as value
      FROM tableB
      GROUP BY tableA_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
     ) b
     ON a.id = b.tableA_id
ORDER BY a.id;
```

This works because if there is only one row in `B` for a given id, then `MAX()` returns the value on that row.